# Excel VBA remove gradient from shape

Tags: vba, excel

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/shape-fill-property-excel

```
 Set myDocument = Worksheets(1) 
    With myDocument.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 90, 90, 90, 50).Fill 
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(128, 0, 0) 
        .BackColor.RGB = RGB(170, 170, 170) 
        .TwoColorGradient msoGradientHorizontal, 1 
    End With
```

How to remove the gradient once it has been added to a shape in Excel?

Comment: `.TwoColorGradient msoGradientHorizontal, 1` - have you tried removing this?

Comment: remove/comment  ".TwoColorGradient msoGradientHorizontal, 1 "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`FillFormat.Solid` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/excel-vba/articles/fillformat-solid-method-excel) will remove any Gradient or Pattern.

The new colour will be the colour at Gradient position 0.

For example, this will remove the gradient from the second shape in the first worksheet:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes(2).Fill.Solid
```